# Emacs buffer shown after closing a buffer

Tags: emacs

How can I modify the way emacs picks which buffer to show after closing a buffer?

When I have multiple columns showing the same buffer, and then open another file in one of the buffers and then close the newly opened buffer, it doesn't switch back to the previous buffer, but to another buffer.

I'll try to explain with an example:

- Start with a new emacs at *scratch*
- C-x 2 (split into two columns)
- C-x C-f 1 (find file 1)
- C-x o (switch to other frame)
- C-x b 1 (find file 1)
- C-x C-f 2 (find file 2)
- C-x k (kill buffer)

Now it switches to *scratch* but I would like it to show 1 in both windows again, is it possible to make emacs behave this way?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but it might help.

Emacs manages its buffer list, including deciding which buffer gets displayed when you kill one (via `kill-buffer`).  I haven't looked into how it's done, but the [documentation is "out there"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/The-Buffer-List.html).  Lots of people have [created](http://geosoft.no/development/emacs.html#Buffer%20Switcher) custom [buffer-stack](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/buffer-stack.el) management magic to change the way emacs does things, maybe some of them are based on bayesian analysis, or whatever. You can imagine the possibilities.

I've never looked into changing the way emacs manages its buffers. Instead I just bind `other-window` and `switch-to-buffer` to easy keystrokes (C-x o, C-x b) and I get really good at using them.

you could create a simple function for what you want: it should destroys all other windows, then split the window so that the current buffer is displayed in both. Luckily, emacs has functions that do exactly those things.

```
(defun cheeso-show-buffer-two-windows ()
  "Close all other windows; then split, and show the current
buffer in both windows."
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-vertically))
```

Bind that to a keystroke, and badda-bing, you're there.  This is a vertical split - the windows are displayed in a vertical stack. If you want it horizontally split (the windows are side-by-side), then replace ... well, you know.

Comment: As you said, not really what I'm looking for. The problem is switch-to-buffers also doesn't want to switch to a buffer that's already visible. If I have file 1 opened in both frames, and then open file 2 in one of the frames and do switch-to-buffer, it doesn't suggest 1, but *scratch*. I looked at the source for emacs,and the function other-buffer (which is used by kill-buffer) has an optional argument, visible-ok, which if set doesn't care if the buffer is visible in another frame. But I don't want to have to recompile emacs just to fix my problem.

Comment: heh heh, I'm quite sure you don't need to recompile emacs to get it to do what you want. I'm no longer clear on what that is.  You said what I proposed is "not really what you're looking for."  Why not?  Whatever it is you're imagining, there's a small bit of elisp that will do what you want. Try looking into `switch-to-buffer-other-window`. Maybe that will be helpful.

Comment: What I want it to do is close the buffer in one frame and switch to the previous buffer that was open in that frame, even though that buffer may be visible in another frame. It's most certainly possible, I just have to learn (e)lisp.

Comment: "... maybe some of them are based on bayesian analysis ... " LOL +1

Answer (score 1):

This also doesn't quite help directly, but [Winner mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode) might help you get where you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tabbar-mode? I had the same problem and for me tabbar was the cause. Tabbar adds the function `tabbar-buffer-kill-buffer-hook` to `kill-buffer-hook`. You can remove it with `(remove-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'tabbar-buffer-kill-buffer-hook)`.

If you don't use tabbar try `M-x describe-variable` `kill-buffer-hook`. One of the functions in this list should be responsible for messing with your buffers.